# « Je suis sur Paris » veut-il dire « je suis à Paris » ?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, registre-familier

On entend parfois dans la langue courante :

> Je suis sur Paris

Est-ce que ça veut dire

> Je suis à Paris

ou y a-t-il des nuances qui les distinguent ?